# Cant get javascript intervals to work

Tags: javascript, onclick

so im a little new to javascript, but im trying to make a progress bar, with some other functionalities, on click of a button. im tring to use the set interval in javascript in order to time the bar, this is my js so far:

```
//Javascript Document

function progress(){
 Var uno = setTimeout("uno()", 3000);
  uno(){
   document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Connecting...";
   document.getElementById("progressInner").style.display = 'block';
   document.getElementById("progressInner").style.width = '20px';
  }   
}
```

From what i have gathered this is how it works, however i am skeptical as it seems i am setting a variable `uno` but not doing anything with it.... from my background in php, thats not how that works :p any pointers you guys can give me on this? my html is here: http://jsbin.com/apoboh/1/edit

right now, it does nothing, it gives me : Uncaught ReferenceError: progress is not defined

Comment: `Var` needs to be lowercase, and uno needs the `function` identifier in front of it.  Also, the timeout assigned to the first uno will get overwritten by your function declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, you are using `setTimeout` not `setInterval`.  The former fires the callback once, the latter indefinitely at a set interval.

Second, these methods return a token that you can use to cancel a setInterval, do this instead

```
function startProgress(){
     // only start progress if it isn't running
     if (!App.progressToken) {  // App is you apps namespace
         App.progressToken = setInterval(function(){
             document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Connecting...";
             document.getElementById("progressInner").style.display = 'block';
             document.getElementById("progressInner").style.width = '20px';
         }, 3000);         
    }
}
```

later, when you want to stop:

```
function stopProgress(){
   clearInterval(App.progressToken);`
   delete App.progressToken
}
```

Comment: That did it, +1 for giving an explanation too not just throwing code my way :)

Comment: np -- i cleaned it up a bit more

Answer (score 0):

The variable `uno` simply holds the handle to the timeout that you just set. You can later use it to clear the timeout before it executes if you need to via a call to [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout).

If you don't need to clear the timeout, then there's really no reason to store the handle at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
function progress(){
  function uno(){
   document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Connecting...";
   document.getElementById("progressInner").style.display = 'block';
   document.getElementById("progressInner").style.width = '20px';
  } 
 var timeoutFunc = setTimeout(uno, 3000);  
}
```

You pass a function to setTimeout which it will call later, not a string.  So this code will define a function uno, and then pass it to setTimeout and delay 3 seconds then call it every 3 seconds after that.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put word "function " before uno()